# estimate distribution of results from one experiment based on earlier experiment

Tags: confidence-interval, stan

I have results from an experiment where I counted how many times I got a positive result from independent bernoulli trials. 
I can estimate the uncertainity on the rate, and get 2.5%-97.5% CI for the rate.

But what I actually want to know is one step further, what will happen when I repeat the experiment on a different sample size, and get CI for the expected outcome of the second experiment.

Do I have to sample from the rate distribution myself and run simulations? seems a pain.

I wanted to this with pystan, I can get estimates for the rate based on experimental results (simple binomial distribution)
But stan doesn't let me set an Int observed parameter. Nor put a real one as the result of a binomial distribution.

What I want is:

exp1res ~ binomial(exp1Size,rate)
exp2res ~ binomial(exp2Size,rate)

given exp1res,exp1Size,exp2Size what is the distribution of exp2res?

Can I do this in pystan? some other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the inference of the rate from the first experiment to predict the number of successes in the second. This should be possible with pystan. Given an experiment with N trials and S successes and a second experiment of size N2, here is my pystan code:

```
data {
    int<lower=1> N;
    int<lower=0> S;
    int<lower=1> N2;
}

parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> rate;
}

model {
    S ~ binomial(N, rate);
}

generated quantities {
    int S2;
    S2 = binomial_rng(N2, rate);
}
```

Printing the fit, I get confidence intervals on S2. For example, with N=20, S=5, and N2=1000 my CI on S2 are:

mean: 274.19

se_mean: 3.35

sd: 91.33

2.5%: 109.0

25%: 207.45

50%: 268.0

75%: 330.0

97.5%: 470.19

And a histogram of the posterior distribution of S2:
[image: posterior samples of S2]

If you want to infer the CI on the *rate* of the second experiment I believe that would depend on a latent discrete parameter (the number of successes in the second experiment) which Stan does not allow. You'd have to marginalize out the discrete parameter.

Comment: This is strange, This had an answer earlier (which simply mentioned generated_quantities and binomial_rng as the solution) and I upvoted it and I think also accepted it, but it seems to be gone now. But this answer is obviously correct and I have already done this and seen it works for be (based on previous vanishing answer) so accepting the answer which I actually see.